# PYODBC Fetchmany to csv only outputting header

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm trying to write a large table to a `csv` using `pyodbc` using `fetchmany()`.  I can connect correctly, but the only record which gets written is the header.  What's the correct way to loop over a db cursor?

```
cxn = pyodbc.connect(cxn data)

mssql_cursor = cxn.cursor()
mssql_cursor.execute(sql_query)

c = csv.writer(open('file.csv', 'w', encoding ='UTF-8', newline='\n'), delimiter='|')
c.writerow([i[0] for i in mssql_cursor.description])
results = mssql_cursor.fetchmany(10000)
while results:
    c.writerows(results)
    results = mssql_cursor.fetchmany(10000)

mssql_cursor.close()
cxn.close()
```

Edit:  It looks that there is nothing being returned via the `fetchmany` method.  I added `print(len(results))` and the result was 0.

Comment: try `c.writerows(list(results))` in while loop

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri same result

Comment: You may have to still iterate the fetched object.

Answer (score 2):

I would keep it simple and just iterate:

```
cxn = pyodbc.connect(cxn data)

mssql_cursor = cxn.cursor()
rows = mssql_cursor.execute(sql_query)

with open('file.csv', 'w', encoding ='UTF-8', newline='\n') as csvfile:
    c = csv.writer(csvfile, delimeter='|')

    for row in rows:
        c.writerow(row)

mssql_cursor.close()
cxn.close()
```

Does that work? If it works here and you want to switch to `executemany()`, it should be fairly easy to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Testing suggests that at least part of your problem stems from the handling of the `file` object associated with the `csv.writer`. Using a context manager (`with` block) to explicitly handle the `file` seems to have solved the problem for me:

```python
with open('file.csv', 'w', encoding ='UTF-8', newline='\n') as csvfile:
    c = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    c.writerow([i[0] for i in mssql_cursor.description])
    results = mssql_cursor.fetchmany(10000)
    while results:
        c.writerows(results)
        results = mssql_cursor.fetchmany(10000)
```